# Sketch button symbol: scalable centered text?

Tags: sketch-app, workflow

I use labels, buttons, filters etc with text in them in my design. I created symbols for all of these to keep it easy to organize.

However, when I use instances to change the text in these buttons, and the text is longer/shorter the text will either not be centered anymore or simply break off. Is there a way to fix this? I imagines the resizing section could do something but there's no 'center' option.

Is this not a default feature of Sketch? Are there plugin alternatives?

[image]

As you can see this is not desired behavior when changing text. I would like the text to be centered at all times and preferably to have the button scale in width with the text as well.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you are not setting the text-alignment to **center** for the text in your symbol button.

You need to do this in the text options:

[image: text-align center selected]

And your text overrides will be centered.

[image: symbol-buttons with centered text inside]

Answer (score 1):

For a flexible button that leverages the Resizing feature within Sketch, scroll down to the **Tips & Tricks** section [of this article](https://medium.com/in-the-hudl/building-our-sketch-library-cd8c925e566) by Michael Fouquet.

Relevant part of the article:

> Doesn’t currently handled nested symbol resizing very well. To get around this, we usually create what we call “spacing blocks”. An example of where this might be necessary is buttons; you drop in a button, give it more text than the default and suddenly the padding is out of whack. For this, we have a show/hide spacing block symbol that drops in semi-transparent “blocks”. The designer now just needs to resize the button until the blocks line up.

[image: Button with spacing blocks that can be toggled on and off]